# Is this boolean expression reducible?

Tags: digital-logic, design

I have this boolean expression: `F1 = a1'a2' + a1a2'`.

Could it be reduced even more?

Comment: Yes. If you can't just see it, write out a logic table and see what you get.

Comment: looks like homework

Comment: @Erion Not exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, factor out the `a2'`. You should see something interesting with what happens to `a1`.

If you don't, post a comment and I can help further.

When you factor out `a2'`, you get `a2'(a1' + a1)`

The statement `a1' + a1` means (a1 or NOT a1). It should be obvious that this is ALWAYS true and thus can be removed from the logic statement. This leaves you with `F1 = a2'`

In general, the tools for reducing logic expressions that I know of are algebraic manipulation (deMorgan's Laws, distributive property, etc.), Karnaugh Maps, and the [Quine McCluskey Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks! You're right. on which law have you based? how did you know this answer?

Comment: To be honest, I just saw it immediately... It's kind of a distributive property I guess. Let me see if I can find some more formal resources about this.

Comment: Thank you. p.s. , you meant to `a1'a2' + a1`, am I right?

Comment: @user1798362, sorry you are still a little off track.

Comment: Just think of it in words: Something is true if a2' is true and a1 is true; or its true if a2' is true and a1 is not true. So does a1 really matter to the final result?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm so sorry both of you, I'd confused with the word "factor out", I though to drop it off. you've probably got that English isn't my native language. I'm sorry again and thank you very much! both of you.